Factoring ideals into prime ideals
I am currently working on a problem from the book “Introductory Algebraic Number Theory” by Kenneth S. Williams and Saban Alaca, and I would like to verify my solution.
The problem is:
Factor $<6>$ into prime ideals in the ring $O_K$ of $K=Q(\sqrt{366})$.
Here’s my approach: 
Square-Free Check: 
I first noted that $366$ is square-free as it can be factored as $366=2⋅3⋅61$
Quadratic Field:
Given that $366$ is square-free, it follows that $Q(\sqrt{366})$ is a quadratic field 
Ideal Factorization:
The ideal $<6>$ can be factored as $<6>=<2>.<3>$ 
Prime Ideal Factorization for $p=2$: 
For $p=2$ and $m=366$
, we have $366 \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$ 
By applying  Theorem $10.2.1$  from the book, we find that $<2> =P^2$, Therefore, $<2>=<2,\sqrt{366} >^2$ 
Prime Ideal Factorization for $p=3$:
For $p=3$
and $m=366$, since $p$ is greater than $2$ and $p$ divides $m$
, the same theorem gives $<3>=P^2$, Therefore, $<3>=<3,\sqrt{366}>^2$
Based on these calculations, it seems reasonable to conclude that $<6>=<2,\sqrt{366}>^2 
 . <3,\sqrt{366}>^2$ 
Is this correct?

Please use LaTeX properly:  your \sqrt366 comes out like $\sqrt{3}66$, which looks terrible.  Put the entire number in braces, as \sqrt{366}.  Then you get $\sqrt{366}$, which is what you want.

Your answer is correct, but since I don't have the book, I have no idea what Theorem 10.2.1 states. Reducing $X^2 - 366$ mod $2$ and $3$ will tell you the factorization of these ideals by Dedekind-Kummer (assuming you know that the ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{366}]$).

@KCd got it , thanks

@ViktorVaughn Thank you so much, I do...
